# How test STDIN in PHPUnit

Tags: php, testing, tdd, phpunit, bdd

I have reader class which read from stdin and return readed value.

```
class Reader 
{
    const STREAM_READ = 'php://stdin';

    private $_streamHandle;

    public function __construct($stream = self::STREAM_READ)
    {
        $this->_streamHandle = fopen($stream, 'r');
    }

    public function getReadedValue()
    {
        $value = trim(fgets($this->_streamHandle));

        return $value;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        fclose($this->_streamHandle);
    }
}
```

Now is my question, how I can test this class, reading something from stdin and return readed value by `getReadedValue()` function?

Comment: execute th script with a command line

Comment: There's a filesystem mocking extension for PHPUnit called vfsStream, which I thought might help but the docs say nothing, so perhaps not. Maybe worth a dig though? It's on GitHub. Alternatively here's a related QA that might be worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158155/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-interactive-console-app

Answer (score 1):

You test the *Reader*, not if STDIN is working or not.

Because you test the unit (the *Reader*) it is not important what that filename is as it is only optional. You can inject something different, for example the filename of a temporary file.

Comment: Good point, any idea how to test that the STDIN is the default stream?